# Move-ADObject - input object cannot be found to any parameters for the command - error

Tags: powershell

Not exactly sure why I am getting this error - **input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the commmand does not take pipeline input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.** Any assistance is appreciated

Code snippet below

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName DC1 -Credential $Cred
Import-Module ActiveDirectory -PSSession $Session
$comp = $env:COMPUTERNAME
if ($ComputerName -eq $null) {
Invoke-Command -Session $session  -ScriptBlock {$using:PC 
}
if($comp.substring(5,3) -imatch "Dbs"){
Get-ADObject $PC |
Move-ADObject  -Targetpath "ou=Database, 
dc=com,dc=company,dc=net"
Write-Host "Moved to Datbases"}

 }


Remove-PSSession -Session $Session
```

Comment: You don't need to establish a remote session to move a computer object if you have the permissions in AD.

Comment: establishing a remote session is a requirement

Comment: "establishing a remote session is a requirement" - not correct, unless you are saying it's a business requirement. It's not a technical requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting the object explicitly?

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName DC01 -Credential $Cred
Import-Module ActiveDirectory -PSSession $Session
$comp = $env:COMPUTERNAME
if($comp.substring(5,3) -imatch "Sys")
{
    $adObject = Get-ADObject -Filter {Name -eq $comp} 
    Move-ADObject -Identity $adObject -Targetpath "ou=System Servers,ou=PRD,ou=Servers,dc=com,dc=myCompany,dc=net" 
}
    elseif($comp.substring(5,3) -imatch "App")
{
```

Comment: You should probably update your question with the code that you are actually running then.

Comment: I get an error Cannot bind parameter Identity. Cannot convert value of type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject". Error: cannot convert CN=xxxxx,OU=xxxx,OU=xxxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx" value of type Deserialized.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer" to type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject"

Comment: Please, please, pretty please...update your question with the code that you are running and the error information.

Comment: Also, try using Get-ADObject instead of Get-ADComputer. I have edited my answer to use this method.

Comment: Get-ADObject instead of Get-ADComputer gives me error : cannot find an object with identity 'computername'

Comment: Is that literally what the error says? If so then there is a syntax error in your code. Unless the computer you are running it on happens to be named 'computername'. Which is of course logically impossible since $comp must have 'sys' as a substring. Please be precise as possible with the information that you are providing.

Comment: your code is not working. for security purposes, i do not include sensitive information in the code

Comment: So sanitize it. **Is that the literal error that you got?** This is not a trivial question. If you literally got that error it indicates that you have a syntax error. If you got a different error (i.e. the actual name of the computer) then it indicates some other issue.

Comment: Read your code and understand what it is doing. At some point you are literally calling Get-ADObject and filtering it to find a computer named 'computername'. That is what the error tells you. Since you won't post the code that you are actually running, you will have to track that issue down.

Comment: Yes I understand. I updated code again to be accurate so you can reference it. The same error applies here. "cannot find an object with identity "PS123DBS12302"

Comment: Please post the actual error in it's entirety. Specifically is it the Get-ADObject or the Move-ADObject that is the problem? Also as Ben H. asks, do you get anything from just the Get-ADObject?

Comment: Cannot find an object with identity: 'PS123DBS12302' under DC=com,DC=BTCorp,DC=net'. +Category Info: ObjectNotFound: (PS123DBS12302:ADObject) [Get-ADObject], ADIdentityNotFoundException + FullyQualifiederrorID: ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.ManagementCommands.GetADBoject + PSComputerName: DC1

Comment: So, do you get anything if you just do ***Get-ADObject PS123DBS12302***

Comment: So then that AD object does not exist. Or there is some other issue with your AD infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

You are both piping in the output of `Get-ADComputer` and also defining the `-Identity` property which are conflicting. Chose one way or the other.

```
Get-ADComputer $comp | Move-ADObject -Targetpath "ou=Database, dc=com,dc=company,dc=net"
```

or

```
$ADComputer = Get-ADComputer $comp
Move-ADObject -Identity $ADComputer -Targetpath "ou=Database, dc=com,dc=company,dc=net"
```

Comment: neither one works, the second one "cannot bind parameter 'Identity'" and the first one"the input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command"

Comment: @HenryB There is an likely an issue with your `$comp` variable. What the output of just `Get-ADComputer $comp`?